# Swagger and swagger ui with spring boot jaxrs and apache cxf

Tags: java, spring, docker, swagger, cxf

Recently my organization took an app that was not originally a spring app, jammed some part sof spring into it, and then migrated the app to docker and kubernetes, prior to this our swagger ui was working well, after the introduction of spring, it no longer works. I have added the swagger2feature to the jaxrsserver bean but i cannot seem to access swqagger ui, it always 404s. Wondering if anyone has any insight into this issue. Also all our endpoints are already anotated with the swagger annotations. Also using Java 8

I tried following every tutorial that details how to setup swagger from scratch with this sort of application configuration